# i need pass variable in url using slash in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I'm new for CodeIgniter.

My **Controller** is:

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }    


    public function index($user)
    {
        if($user != '')
        {
            if($this->session->userdata('user_id'))
            {
                echo 'user in';
            }
            else
            {
                redirect('/');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'wrong page';
        }
    }
}
```

1st of all i logged into this site.
If i give url like `http://localhost/picyou/user` it show 'wrong page'...

If i give url like `http://localhost/picyou/user/fh` it show '404 Error'...

But I need to display "user in".

Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the URL to work you need to include the function name

```
http://localhost/picyou/user/index/fh
```

If you want to don't want to have `index` in the url then you need to look at [URI routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
localhost/sitename/class/function/ID
```

In this way you can call any function of the controller with argument.
    The first segment represents the controller class that should be invoked.
    The second segment represents the class function, or method, that should be called.
    The third, and any additional segments, represent the ID and any variables that will be passed to the controller.

Comment: that ok... but i want to do like, what im asking... Wt to do?

Comment: What printed when you gave above url?